# Catch the unknown picture on <img> tag and set default image

Tags: javascript, html, image, onerror

I have this image tag :

```
<img id="viewerofinstore" src="{{filteredArray[imageIndex]}}" 
onError="this.style.visibility = 'hidden'"   
onload="this.style.visibility = 'visible'"  width="297px" height="297px" />
```

The `src` of images are changed every second with other image, but there are some cases that the image is worng and an unknown image appear.

I add the `"onError="this.style.visibility = 'hidden'"` but sometimes I can see the unknown image for a second before its hidden.

I want to catch the unknown image before display it and put a default image or hide the image.

Answer (score 3):

you can make the img hidden by default, and only make it visible if it loads correctly.

```
<img id="viewerofinstore" src="{{filteredArray[imageIndex]}}" style="visibility:hidden"   
onload="this.style.visibility = 'visible'"  width="297px" height="297px" />
```